# app freezes and takes long time to respond while opening

Tags: android, android-service, runnable, android-handler

I have an app in which Service is running in background also i am using Handler.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seconds);

    if(!isMyServiceRunning(serv.class))
     {
        startService(new Intent(this, serv.class));
     } else {

        Log.e("Shiva","Service already running");
    }

    status = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);
    btn_send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(this);
    contlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contlist);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String y = prefs.getString("mobstat",null);
    status.setText(y);
    status.setSelection(status.getText().length());
    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false))
    {
        try
        {
            getNumber(seconds.this.getContentResolver());
        } catch (JSONException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    nonstoprun();
}



private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass)
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(update);
    Log.e("Shiva","Handler Stopped");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   nonstoprun();
    Log.e("Shiva","Handler Started");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(update);
}

private void nonstoprun()
{
    handler = new Handler();
    update = new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             if(!isRunning) {
                 isRunning = true;
                 musers = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
                 descAdapter = new DescAdapter(seconds.this, musers, seconds.this);
                 int index = contlist.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                 View v = contlist.getChildAt(0);
                 int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - contlist.getPaddingTop());
                 contlist.setAdapter(descAdapter);
                 contlist.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
              } else {
                 isRunning = false;
             }
        }
    };
          handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
```

My app will run a specific method to fetch the data from server and update it in the sqllite db. So to update listview with new db values for this purpose i am using handler. So when ever i opened the app it is very slow in opening and takes long time. Sometimes app wasn't not responding. Scrolling listview also not smooth which stucks. Please help me that implementation what i did is correct? Please help.

Solution:

In Oncreate i added the below lines:

```
 musers = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
 descAdapter = new DescAdapter(this,musers,this);
 contlist.setAdapter(descAdapter);
```

Then

```
private void nonstoprun()
{

    update = new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
                 ArrayList<mobstat> musers1 = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
                 setData(musers1);
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

         private void setData(ArrayList<mobstat> musers1)
         {
                 musers.clear();
                 musers.addAll(musers1);
                 descAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     };
          handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
```

Using the above code i am able to update list successfully. But still app is slow while opening. Any suggestions.

Comment: For starters-  you don't need to check if your service is running.  Just start it.  If it was already started, a new one won't be launched.

Comment: @GabeSechan- Thank you i will implement in the way you said.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks..what for stopservice?

Comment: @CoDfather Not sure what you're asking.  But one stopService will stop the service, no matter how many times it has been started.  So only stop it when you're sure you need it stopped.  So only call it if you're sure nothing else continues to need it.

Comment: @GabeSechan But I mean that is it necessary to check whether the service is running or not to stop it using stopservice?

Comment: @CoDfather No it isn't.  In fact it will return true if it kills the service and false if it can't find one to kill.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're constantly creating a new adapter and setting it.  That will destroy your performance.  You need to make it so that your adapter can change data, rather than being recreated.  That will also mean you won't need that setSelectionFromTop code, which will also kill performance being repeatedly looped.  Fix those two things and you'll probably be good.

Comment: Could you provide an example for adapter what you mentioned? I am updating listview with new values so i used this way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One easy way is to provide a function setData(List<whatever>)  That function would replace the old list with the new one, then call notifyDataSetChanged();.  That would be enough to replace the data.  YOu can get fancier, but try that first.

Comment: public void SetData(List<Receipt> newlist) {
    musers.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}   then called setData inside handler run --> musers = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);    setData(musers); but i am getting nullpointer exception